# Map only shows partially in a Splitview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a Splitview and in detailed view I just added a map view there. I did nothing else than including the location and map libraries so the build and run will work.

However, the map shows only partially, do you have any idea why this is happening and how should I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

[Here](http://www.2shared.com/file/hqOzhjOr/SplitApp5.html) is the project and thanks a lot!

Regards, Yashu!

Comment: i want to post a picture here but I was not allowed!

Comment: Can you put an image up elsewhere and provide a link for us?

Comment: As I said, I cannot upload image:) But I have solved this problem by just moving the mapview object to the upper level in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autoresizing mask of the map view is not set up correctly. It should have a flexible width and height like its superview.

Comment: I found out the problem: in the storyboard the mapview was embedded in a view. once I moved it out and up to one level up, everything works then.